# Solve equation $y' - 8x\sqrt{y} = \frac{4xy}{x^2 - 1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' - 8x\sqrt{y} = \frac{4xy}{x^2 - 1}$

I think I should reduce it to the Bernoulli equation with `n = $\frac{1}{2}$`, but have no idea how.

Comment: Please edit the question in detail: What have you attempted thus far?  (Show us your work).  What don't you understand, specifically?  Where specifically are you stuck? How would you know to reduce it to Bernoulli equation, but have no idea how?  Please understand that this website is not a "do my homework for me" service.

Comment: It's already a Bernoulli's differential equation.

Comment: @amWhy, I cannot specify it, it was just a wish to have an explanation in crucial transitions, not just raw math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y' - 8x\sqrt{y} = \frac{4xy}{x^2 - 1}$$
This is Bernoulli differential equation. Divide by $\sqrt y$:
$$\dfrac {y'}{\sqrt y}  -\frac{4x\sqrt y}{x^2 - 1}=8x$$
Note that $(\sqrt y)'=\dfrac 12 \dfrac {y'}{\sqrt y}$

So that you can substitute $v=\sqrt y$:
$$2v'  -\frac{4xv}{x^2 - 1}=8x$$
$$v'  -\frac{2xv}{x^2 - 1}=4x$$
It's a linear first ode that you should be able to solve.